# Does research show that Metformin alleviates/mitigates Adult Acne in PCOS women?

Tags: research, female, pcos, metformin

I'm an adult woman in her 30's, who suffers from Poly-Cystic-Ovarian-Syndrome (PCOS). My doctor has proscribed me Metformin to treat/manage my PCOS. Since PCOS can be one of the several causes for Adult Acne, ***does research show that Metformin alleviates/mitigates Adult Acne in PCOS women?***

I'm having my engagement photos done soon, and my Adult Acne is still going strong. I was wondering if Metformin is not meant to help with Acne... or if... my Acne would just be worse without it?!